# Select the first 3 sibling elements (<p>) of another element (<h2>)

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How do I select all the `<p>` tags that are siblings to the first 3 `<h2>` tags using CSS?

The tags with the text "one", "two", "three" should be red but the text "four", and "five" should not be selected.

Here is my example code but I am not sure what that CSS selector should look like.

```css
.container h2 + p {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>Some text</h2>
  <p>One</p>
  <h2>Some text</h2>
  <p>Two</p>
  <p>Two</p>
  <h2>Some text</h2>
  <p>Three</p>
  <p>Three</p>
  <p>Three</p>
  <h2>Some text</h2>
  <p>Four</p>
  <p>Four</p>
  <p>Four</p>
  <p>Four</p>
  <h2>Some text</h2>
  <p>Five</p>
  <p>Five</p>
  <p>Five</p>
  <p>Five</p>
  <p>Five</p>
</div>
```

Comment: how many h2 do you will have it ? is it dynamic or static ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really have to select all the `p` elements that follow the first three `h2` elements, you will have to use as many complex selectors as there are `p` elements that match that criteria — no two ways about it. Selectors doesn't provide a pseudo-class for matching n elements that follow another element, nor does it provide one for matching elements between two other elements (so you can't, for example, write a selector that matches all elements between `h2:nth-of-type(3)` and `h2:nth-of-type(4)`).

```css
.container h2:nth-of-type(-n+3) + p,
.container h2:nth-of-type(-n+3) + p + p,
.container h2:nth-of-type(-n+3) + p + p + p {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>Some text</h2>
  <p>One</p>
  <h2>Some text</h2>
  <p>Two</p>
  <p>Two</p>
  <h2>Some text</h2>
  <p>Three</p>
  <p>Three</p>
  <p>Three</p>
  <h2>Some text</h2>
  <p>Four</p>
  <p>Four</p>
  <p>Four</p>
  <p>Four</p>
  <h2>Some text</h2>
  <p>Five</p>
  <p>Five</p>
  <p>Five</p>
  <p>Five</p>
  <p>Five</p>
</div>
```

If overriding is not out of the question, then it becomes much, much easier — you can simply override it with a different selector instead:

```css
.container h2 ~ p {
  color: red
}

.container h2:nth-of-type(4) ~ p {
  color: currentColor
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>Some text</h2>
  <p>One</p>
  <h2>Some text</h2>
  <p>Two</p>
  <p>Two</p>
  <h2>Some text</h2>
  <p>Three</p>
  <p>Three</p>
  <p>Three</p>
  <h2>Some text</h2>
  <p>Four</p>
  <p>Four</p>
  <p>Four</p>
  <p>Four</p>
  <h2>Some text</h2>
  <p>Five</p>
  <p>Five</p>
  <p>Five</p>
  <p>Five</p>
  <p>Five</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!  Do you mind if I ask, what is the `-n` in `nth-of-type(-n+3)`?

Comment: @Mdd: It forces n to count backwards to ensure that the +3 only matches the first three elements, 3, 2, 1.

Comment: @Mdd: I added an alternative in case it works for you.

Comment: @BoltClock currentColor ofc!

Answer (score 2):

use `:nth-of-type()`

#### snippet

```css
.container h2:nth-of-type(-n+3) + p {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>Some text</h2>
  <p>One</p>
  <h2>Some text</h2>
  <p>Two</p>
  <p>Two</p>
  <h2>Some text</h2>
  <p>Three</p>
  <p>Three</p>
  <p>Three</p>
  <h2>Some text</h2>
  <p>Four</p>
  <p>Four</p>
  <p>Four</p>
  <p>Four</p>
  <h2>Some text</h2>
  <p>Five</p>
  <p>Five</p>
  <p>Five</p>
  <p>Five</p>
  <p>Five</p>
</div>
```

To select **ALL** instead the adjacent `p` to `h2` you need more complex selectors:

#### Snippet

```css
.container h2:nth-of-type(-n+3) + p,
.container h2:nth-of-type(-n+3) + p + p,
.container h2:nth-of-type(-n+3) + p + p + p {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>Some text</h2>
  <p>One</p>
  <h2>Some text</h2>
  <p>Two</p>
  <p>Two</p>
  <h2>Some text</h2>
  <p>Three</p>
  <p>Three</p>
  <p>Three</p>
  <h2>Some text</h2>
  <p>Four</p>
  <p>Four</p>
  <p>Four</p>
  <p>Four</p>
  <h2>Some text</h2>
  <p>Five</p>
  <p>Five</p>
  <p>Five</p>
  <p>Five</p>
  <p>Five</p>
</div>
```

Comment: what the diffrent above answer ?

Comment: This does not select all the `<p>` tags with the text "two" or "three" though.

Comment: I updated answer to match **all** `p` like Bolt did, there is no other way there I can see.

Comment: Actually there is but not using the adjacent + but the sibling ~

Answer (score 1):

EDITED due to question clarification:

As BoltClock says, there is no selector for that. But you can turn it around, and select all `<p>` after the fourth `<h2>` and make them *not* red:

```css
.container p {
  color: red;
}
.container h2:nth-of-type(4) ~ p {
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>Some text</h2>
  <p>One</p>
  <h2>Some text</h2>
  <p>Two</p>
  <p>Two</p>
  <h2>Some text</h2>
  <p>Three</p>
  <p>Three</p>
  <p>Three</p>
  <h2>Some text</h2>
  <p>Four</p>
  <p>Four</p>
  <p>Four</p>
  <p>Four</p>
  <h2>Some text</h2>
  <p>Five</p>
  <p>Five</p>
  <p>Five</p>
  <p>Five</p>
  <p>Five</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This only selects the first `<p>` tag adjacent to the `<h2>` though.  Not all of the tags with the text "two" or "three".

Comment: @Mdd: That is correct. This is what your question asked. The other `<p>` tags are not adjacent to the selected `<h2>`.

Comment: I apologize @Amadan.  I will edit the question.  I meant the <p> tags that would be siblings of the first 3 `<h2>` tags than.